# Recurring calendar event on First of the month

Tags: icalendar, rrule

I have a recurring calendar event on 1st of each month, when 1st falls on Sat/Sun is it possible for iCal to schedule it for last working day Fri?

Answer (score 3):

If I understood you correctly the following RRULE should do the trick:

```
FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=1MO,1TU,1WE,1TH,1FR,-1FR;BYMONTHDAY=1,-1,-2
```

See the [next 100 instances](http://recurrence-expansion-service.appspot.com/reaas?dtstart=20160801&rrule=FREQ%3DMONTHLY%3BBYDAY%3D1MO%2C1TU%2C1WE%2C1TH%2C1FR%2C-1FR%3BBYMONTHDAY%3D1%2C-1%2C-2&skip=&max_instances=100&expansion_window_end=21000101T000000)

It basically does two things:

1. Iterate the first weekday that falls on the 1st day of the month
2. Iterate the last Friday of each month that falls on the last or 2nd last day of the month (in which cases the 1st of the next month falls on Saturday or Sunday).

A slightly shorter version that should yield the same results is

```
FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=1MO,1TU,1WE,1TH,FR;BYMONTHDAY=1,-1,-2
```

This just iterates every Friday, but only keeps the ones that fall on the first, last and 2nd last day of each month. Though it looks like the recurrence expansion service above disagrees. That's probably a bug.

Comment: @Marten what about the same rule for the 2nd of the month, but same thing where we want to go backwards if it occurs on a weekend? I can come up with a way with 3 RRULEs, but not one

Comment: @manroe I can't come up with a single rule doing this. It should be possible with two rules `FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR;BYMONTHDAY=2` and `FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=FR;BYMONTHDAY=1,-1`. The first one handles the regular case when the 2nd falls on a working day, the second one handles the weekend case. It only iterates Fridays which fall on the first or last day of a month (in these two cases the 2nd falls on the weekend).

Comment: @Marten thanks for replying - figured I'd give it a shot! :P

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean "the last working day Friday *of the previous month*", in which case I don't think it possible. It would mean that some months have 2 occurrences when others have 0, which doesn't really work.

You could easily do the *first working day of the month* (the 1st, or the first Monday):

```
FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR;BYSETPOS=1
```

Or, you could do *always* the last working day of the month:

```
FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR;BYSETPOS=-1
```

Comment: Scenario 1 is what I require I.e. some months have 2 occurpancies while others have none.